# Upgrade laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello after I installed Laravel,
I try to update the version 5.5 to 5.6 and unable to throws me an error:
 - laravel/framework v5.6.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.

I use XAMPP with PHP 7.2.10.
I installed Composer with php 7 And does not help.
Thanks

Comment: on your cmd you can run `php -v` to see the actual version. Due to mutiple php installation, sometimes it happens.

Comment: If I check in CMD registered PHP 7.0.10 . But in path C:\xampp\php I get PHP 7.2.10 . How to coordinate their sons? Project Save On XAMPP folder. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your `composer.json`. It is possible that there is a configuration parameter `config.platform.php` which contains the value `7.0.10`. This feature allows to simulate a specific PHP version to composer. If you don't need it, you can remove it or force composer to install anyway by using the `--ignore-platform-reqs` parameter when updating the packages.

Comment: Thank you i'm run $ composer update --ignore-platform-reqs and it's work!

Comment: The php version dependency is there because Laravel is using features that were introduced in that version. Telling composer to ignore the dependency might allow it to install, but will cause it to fail during runtime whenever a page is requested that uses one of those unsupported features

Comment: @TravisBritz Surely that has to be kept in mind. But as the author mentioned he is on v7.2.10, I'd assumed that will be no problem.

Comment: In cases where a package requires an arbitrary php version it's a fine solution, but in this case Laravel actually does need php 7.1 for some components. Since they're getting this error it indicates that v7.2.10 *isn't actually being used*, so ignoring the version requirement just hides the error until it causes issues later, instead of fixing the cause (some kind of misconfiguration).

Comment: I get your point, but that's already part of my answer as well (and to be precise, my answer starts with that). It's just that I don't like repeating what other answers or comments already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux `Debian`, you can easily install the latest version of php with `sudo apt-get install php x.x`. On windows, [this link](http://php.net/downloads.php) might help. Then, try installing or upgrading Laravel from `cmd` and it should work sweet! Re-installing the latest verion of XAMPP may also do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I use Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your system's `PATH` environment variable so that it finds the newer version of php from your command line. You might have more than one installed right now, so it uses the first one it finds when it looks through the directories defined in your PATH. After updating the path variable, you might have to log out for it to apply.

You can check the version used by your command line with `php --version`. To see which version Apache is configured with, use [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).